# My cellular networks slower than USB tethering, what shoud i do?

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, mobile-network, 3g, usb-tethering

In the first glance to my title, it doesn't really make sense because the hotspot itself should equal/faster than the client who borrow/tether the network, but due to unknown reason, it always slower, and not a bit slower.

I'm not the only one have [this problem](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m7/274244-internet-slow-phone-but-fast-tethering.html).

My phone model is Oukitel K4000(non-root). Originally i'm not even can access the https website, such as https://www.google.com:

[image]

But USB/wifi tethering works fine even though slow which take 1 minute to load mobile(spoof with mobile user agent) https://www.google.com.

Then i found it's because of Oukitel misplaced MMS proxy and port in normal proxy and port field, the https works after i remove this fields:

[image]

And it's faster, USB/tethering which take 1 minute to load https://www.google.com now only require 30 seconds.

But still, there's something wrong because cellular network is ALWAYS slower than USB tethering.

Speedtest app in my phone:

[image]

In average, downland speed is 3 times slower than my laptop who tethering:
[image]

I also test with chrome remote debugging, http://android.blogspot.my/ (no https), spends 25 seconds:

[image]

And the result of laptop chrome(mobile user agent) who use USB tethering(wifi tethering is slower but still faster than mobile), spends 1.5 seconds:

[image]

I perform a lot of testing, so i can conclude that my phone is abnormally slower than USB tethering. I also test my phone to connect wifi, it spends only 1.25 second to load http://android.blogspot.my/, so i can conclude that the problem only exist on cellular networks.

I tried to use [DNS changer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.burakgon.dnschanger&hl=en) but i think the app doesn't works because even i set custom DNS to invalid ip like 10.3.6.8, my phone still able to load web pages.

I failed to [root](http://www.chinaphonearena.com/forum/Thread-Question-Oukitel-K4000-root) my phone too.

I wonder it might because the app in my phone use ipv6 as first priority(which always fail if i request ipv6 in USB tethering), i'm not really sure.

I get lost, what should i do ?